# Activate user via email in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm still learning Rails and I have a simple project where users sign up by providing their email and password.  I want the user to be in an inactive state until he clicks an email link.  I followed RailCasts' example for resetting a password and this is what I came up with:

I added two new fields to my User model:

- activation_token:string
- active:boolean

Inside `User.rb` I have the following two methods:

```
def send_activation
  generate_token(:activation_token)
  UserMailer.activation(self).deliver
end

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

I created a new controller called `ActivationsController` and have one method inside it:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find_by_activation_token(params[:id])

    @user.update_attribute(:active, true)
    flash[:success] = "Your account is now activated."
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Inside `routes.rb` I added this route:

```
resources :activations, only: [:update]
```

I created a `UserMailer` with the following method:

```
def activation(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Account Activation"
end
```

`rake routes` says the following:

```
activation PUT  /activations/:id(.:format)  activations#update
```

Inside `activation.text.erb` I have this:

```
To activate your account, please click the link below:
<%= link_to activation_url(@user.activation_token), method: :put %>
```

Now when I try to sign up a user I get this error before the email gets sent out:

```
No route matches {:method=>:put}
```

any ideas?

mike

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the link-text:

```
<%= link_to 'TEXT', activation_url(@user.activation_token), method: :put %>
```

Comment: now I get this error: 

No route matches [GET] "/activations/icrvr5uNahnA5fpVjVTDEw"

Comment: you have to make it a get request in your routes. put only works in your browser with some rails ujs magick

Comment: With a PUT I get this URL /activations/:id(.:format) which has a place for an :id which I can get to through params[:id].  But with a GET I get /activations(.:format).  Is there a way to get an :id into the URL with a GET request? Or is there another way I can get to the activation_token?

Comment: just create some resource that matches what you want! ```match 'activations/:id' => "activations#update"```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but I was also having this problem. I wanted to answer it to help anyone else out.

I believe the problem is using an activation#update action, where you should be using an activation#edit action, as that action uses a GET request instead of a PATCH request. Since the user is receiving this in an email (and thus is outside of the Rails server), it should be a plain old GET link_to.

Further, at least in RAILs 4 (which this question is probably way before) you can add params to your url path with a hash after the initial variable. So...

`<%= link_to "TEXT", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, 
                                                 email: @user.email)`

(That's if you want to authenticate the activation_token with the user's email.)

I'm not sure how the rest of your code is setup, but as regards to your last comment on the first answer, here's something from railstutorial.org/book that I found helpful...

> Because we’re modeling activations using an Account Activations resource, the 
>   token itself can appear as the argument of the named route

Also, this book points out (in a footnote) why we want to use an edit action instead of an update...

> It might even make more sense to use an update action, but the activation link needs to be sent in an email and hence should involve a regular browser click, which issues a GET request instead of the PATCH request required by the update action.

Source: [Rails Tutorial: Chapter 10](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#cha-10_footnote-3)